# PDO/SQL Select * from function showing no results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using this PHP function:

```
if(!function_exists("SelectQuery2")) {
    function SelectQuery2($table, array $where) {
        //PDO
        global $pdo_conn;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ";
        $values = null;
        if ($where) {
            $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", array_map(function ($c) { return "`$c` = ?"; }, array_keys($where)));
            $values = array_values($where);
        }
        $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($values);
    }
}
```

And I am calling it here:

```
$where = array(" ticketnumber = ".$_GET["seq"]." ");
$ticket=SelectQuery2("tickets", $where);
$ticket = $ticket[0];
```

but I am not getting any results.

I use `$ticket["column_name"]` to show my results.

What could be the problem?

Comment: @YourCommonSense We cannot ask informative/canonical questions, we cannot fix codes, so what we do here?

Comment: @Mr.Alien downvoting?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I don't do that either :) also, code is provided, he attempted, so on what grounds should we down vote?

Comment: First of all you're not returning anything in your function

Comment: @Mr.Alien if you have any questions, you are more than welcome to ask them on meta.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually I often close questions, but seemed a bit unfair here, as he provided the code, he tried, and it failed, so according to me, downvoting is not justified here :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense there is a question despite there's no actual question sentence. In each question, you would need to fix code. Someone showed a try, and fails. If there's a question sentence, you would need to provide at least one line of code to show the direction, so you are still fixing code, aren't you?

Comment: @RoyalBg please don't argue with me. If you don't like the rules - complain on meta, not here. I do understand that you would like as many bad questions as possible as they'll bring you more rep. However, for the site it would be a disaster. That's why you should close duplicate and offtopic questions, instead of answering them. Dynamical query using PDO is a sure duplicate too, answered hundred times already. If you want to violate rules - it's your choice, but don't ask me for the approval, thank you.

Comment: charliejsford, you may want to actually formulate a question statement so others don't dismiss it as "fix my code for me". You are posting a question after all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know you do want the site to be used only from 5+ year experienced programmers which are asking about real big problems, but that's it. The site is appearing on first places in google, and people find it, so they ask questions. We don't ask you for approval, we just point out that you are starting with arrogance to ones who are new. Yes, the OP did not do anything to test its code, it actually isn't his own code, but copies from somewhere, but it will be good to give him directions, and then leave it to the wolves, instead of kill the unborn in the womb

Comment: @BoltClock when formulated, it turned to be to duplicate. What would be your move then? You'd ask someone to volunteer to find a link?

Comment: @Your Common Sense: If I were the one calling this out as a duplicate, I'd find the link. But I'm not.

Comment: @BoltClock this is the very problem. It's just impossible to find anything on this site, polluted with millions of such one-time disposable questions from help vampires. With one hand you ask us to follow the rules and with other you're barring us from doing so.

Comment: By the way, most likely this function is prone to SQL injection. But of course nobody cares of such *trifle* matters.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is trivial.

Comment: @BoltClock the word I am looking for is "quality". At least under PHP tag Stack Overflow making world worse.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You're perfectly welcome to explain any potential SQL injection to the OP, you can't get on your high horse about nobody doing that when you can't be bothered to do it yourself

Comment: @Clive this remark was just to emphasize concerns of the usual participant. Their first concern is to get rep points, the second is to comfort a downvoted, and third is to reward with an upvote something that looks like decent answer. While actual reading either question or answer is apparently not among primary goals and seldom performed at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense My mistake, no offence intended. I guess I have a different experience of SO, that's not how I perceive it at all

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating such a complicated function, why don't you check first the returning values?

I did this test

```
function SelectQuery2($table, array $where) {


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ";
        $values = null;
        if ($where) {
            $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", array_map(function ($c) { return "`$c` = ?"; }, array_keys($where)));
            $values = array_values($where);
        }
        return array($sql, $values);
    }

$where = array("ticketnumber = asdasdasd", "ticketbla = dfgdfgdfg");
$ticket=SelectQuery2("tickets", $where);
var_dump($ticket);
```

And the output is:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `0` = ? AND `1` = ?' (length=49)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'ticketnumber = asdasdasd' (length=26)
      1 => string 'ticketbla = dfgdfgdfg' (length=21)
```

So, are you expecting your column names to be `0` and `1`, instead of the real column names?

I guess - no. You need `array_keys()` in the closure, but you are passing `array $where` as numeric array (with only values), so the keys are `0`, `1`, etc...

You would need an associative array, which passes the column name as `key` because the closure requires it this way, and the value as `value` because the `PDOStatement::execute` requires it this way, when not using named placeholders, but `?`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
The appropriate example from here is:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array($calories, $colour));
?>
```

Which says that `execute()` here accepts the values `150` and `red` as array values (`array(150, 'red')`) which in your case will be (`array($_GET["seq"])`).

The right example of the passed array should be:

```
$where = array('ticketnumber' => $_GET["seq"]);
```

If you need multiple column names and values, just add more key => value pairs.

```
$where = array(
    'ticketnumber' => $_GET["seq"],
    'ticket_owner' => $_GET['owner'],
    'ticket_etc' => $_GET['etc']
);
```

But, here you have some disadvantages:

**Your function is strictly complicated to rules `col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2 AND...`. Your SELECT query is only for simple data extraction. You barely can use SQL functions, HAVING clauses, date operators, BETWEEN, nor `<`; `>`.**

That's why I would not suggest this variant of wrapping PDO. At its nature, PDO is already some kind of wrapper. At least don't make the query string dynamic. You can try to wrap the `prepare()`, `execute()`, `fetch()`, but stop there. Also don't do it in procedural PHP functions. It will just increase the agony of bad design, such as using globals, because your PDO object is not shared between them.

Comment: And who did the downvote maybe wants to explain? :)

Comment: when i do the var_dump on $ticket it shows NULL

Comment: @charliejsford yes, it shows null, because you are passing the values to PDO. My test function skipped your lines of executing, and returning the values you use to the pdo driver. You are using `prepare($sql)` and `execute($values)` so I have returned the values and dumped the function.

Comment: so, how is that an answer. its not helping me really

Comment: @charliejsford it does, read it all. It shows you how to find the mistake, and where it is. It's in the array definition. You need `'ticketnumber' => $_GET['seq']` instead of one whole value.

Comment: do i need to change my function code too?

Comment: var_dump is showing: array(2) { [0]=> string(48) "SELECT * FROM `tickets` WHERE `ticketnumber` = ?" [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "34828" } }

Comment: If you change the array to associative as I suggested, you will have this result that you shown. Otherwise you will have `WHERE 0 = ?`. So, no, you don't need to change the function. Just the array.

Comment: it looks like : $where = array('ticketnumber' => $_GET['seq']);

Comment: and the function as it is in my question, with the above in the $where of the function it shows NULL

Comment: Ok, maybe you need to edit the function and remove `array_values()` function: `$values = $where;` or simply pass `$where` to `execute()`.

Comment: ok i tried removing array_values($where) and using $stmt->execute($values); but that didn't work and also tried $stmt->execute($where); but still nothing

Comment: It's OK. It's not supposed to return anything. Leave the `array_values()` again. I just tested it and work as intended. An execute() does not return result set. If you add additional `return $stmt->fetch();` at the and of the function, you will have result set

Comment: thats working now. in my $where variable how do i so something like $where = array('ticket number => $_GET["seq"]); then put an AND column2 = 123

Comment: Add one more key=>value pair to your array.

Comment: but the function uses an implode for AND, do i need to put the and in anywhere?

Comment: No, you just pass 1 or more key=>value pairs, the function implodes them and add the keys as column names separated with `AND`.

Comment: How about if I need to use or? Or if i need to do WHERE column1 = 123 AND (col2 > 1 or col1 = 1)

Comment: Then you will need separated functions, or add conditions in the function. You explicitly said in your function `AND` and `=`. You can make them variables, and params. Them pass them to the function. In fact it's not good idea to build this kind of functions over PDO. You will end up with mess like `$clauses = array('AND', 'OR', 'OR', 'AND');` `$signs = array('<', '=', '=', '>');` `$where = array('col1' => val1, 'col2' => val2, 'col3' => val3, 'col4' => val4); $ticket=SelectQuery2("tickets", $where, $clauses, $signs);` I don't see any better than using native PDO without wrapping in function.

Comment: May I ask you a question? Do you use PDO in your own projects?

Comment: @YourCommonSense No, in most of them, I am not. I use it in one of my projects and I did the mistake to try to make a wrapper over it. That's why I'm not suggesting this to the OP.